What are good reference sites and tools for Lego enthusiasts?
What web sites, resources, and tools do enthusiasts use?  It would be helpful to have a list of these available to reference in the future.

I'm curious, why is this on meta? It's not about our site, is it?

@BoltClock: It's quite literally a meta-question - "Where do we find answers to questions?" It's not a question about Lego, but a question to help people better answer questions about Lego.

http://bricks.stackexchange.com

LOL and +1 for the world's most obvious answer. :D

Peeron/PICSL is one of the oldest and most comprehensive databases of parts and sets.
Bricklink is an online marketplace that also maintains a massive parts database.
Brickipedia is less comprehensive than Peeron but has details on more non-toy aspects of Lego, and after years of dealing with MediaWiki and knockoffs, I find it easier to use than Peeron.

Eurobricks news and forums
Lugnet if only for the archive 
Classic Castle news and forums
History Bricks my favorite blog, all the mocs I need!
Brickshelf everybody's mocs
MOCpages nicer moc posting environment

Brickset: LEGO set guide
LEGO: the homepage of a company started by a Danish carpenter, has some interesting info
rec.toys.lego roll call: some rec.toys.lego archives
LDraw: one of the most comprehensive parts database and foundation fo numerous CAO tools. Peeron uses it too.

Here are some notable BIONICLE and Hero Factory resources:

http://bzpower.com

A BIONICLE fansite and forum (note there IS a LEGO Discussion forum, and a Hero Factory forum)

http://biosector01.com

A BIONICLE storyline wiki (we do have brief set information on pages that have set forms)

http://hf.biosector01.com

A Hero Factory (operated by the above BIONICLE wiki as well) (set information as well)


